# Azure URL Rewrite any URL without extension

Tags: regex, azure, url-rewriting, cdn, azure-cdn

I'm trying to set up Azure CDN so that any requests that come through without an extension are 'rewrote' to just URL '/'.

E.g.  `http://example.com/test/`
becomes > `http://example.com`

but `http://example.com/static/js/index.js`
is ignored and passes through unchanged.

How can I do this using Azure CDN management UI?

[image]

Comment: Not sure if I get it... `index.js` has an extension

Comment: Basically need to detect if a url has a `.` in it which suggests it's static content (css or js files) so do not do anything with this URL the file should exist in blob storage so so let it go unchanged and the file is served.

If it doesn't contain a `.` then it's routing via client side routes (in react using react-router) so rewrite it to just `/` where the azure blob storage is configured to to load `/index.html` and the route in the URL segments should be picked up ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So I've found that the main pattern to use is `[^?.]*(\?.*)?$` as the source
Then just `index.html` as the destination.  You have to wait a long time for it to take affect, and I've found that even when it says the rule is 'active' - you may have to still wait another few hours.

So basically, be very patient until 'active', then wait some more, then it may be active.  What a good system... not

For a full write up of the feature and explanation of what I was trying to achieve, see this article:
https://medium.com/@antbutcher89/hosting-a-react-js-app-on-azure-blob-storage-azure-cdn-for-ssl-and-routing-8fdf4a48feeb